# SmartGwt - Removing one tab clears the canvas

Tags: gwt, tabs, smartgwt

I've built a GUI with a SmartGWT TabSet with Tabs that can be dynamically added and removed.
The Tabs share the same canvas which is moved from Tab to Tab at each tab selection like this:

```
myTabSet.addTabSelectedHandler(new TabSelectedHandler() {

    public void onTabSelected(TabSelectedEvent event) {
    [...]
    myTabs[myTabSet.getSelectedTabNumber()].setPane(myCanvas);

    // Then I fill the contained widgets with the tab-specific data

    }
}
```

This works, but when I try to remove a Tab with

```
myTabSet.removeTab(iToBeDeletedTab);
```

The tab is removed but the remaining tabs have a blank pane, I can get the content back only by reloading the page. I found that I have to prevent pane destruction with calls to :

```
myTabSet.setDestroyPanes(false);
```

and

```
myTabSet.updateTab(iToBeDeletedTab, null);                          
//called right before
myTabSet.removeTab(iToBeDeletedTab);
```

I understand that the canvas/pane is still destroyed, but I cannot figure out how to prevent this.
Has anyone any hint?
Thank you!

Comment: I didn't catch what do you do when you delete a tab: what do you set to the tab as pane when you indicate the tab to show after the delete

Comment: Before removing the tab I change the selected tab to tab 0 with `myTabSet.selectTab(0);`
then I set the pane
`myTabs[myTabSet.getSelectedTabNumber()].setPane(myCanvas);`

Comment: I will make a try this evening

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the redraw() method after removing a tab? This usually helps me when loading/reloading data with smartGWT widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Your calls are correct, but now what you've got is the pane completely unnassociated from the TabSet and not drawn (check the Watch Tab in the Developer Console and you'll see this).  Now, call updateTab(someOtherTab, pane) to connect the pane to one of the other tabs where it should be showing.

Comment: Thanks, this make sense. Now I do so but I get this error message:
_A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list]_

What I'm calling now is:

`toBeDeletedTab.setPane(null);`
       `myTabSet.updateTab(iToBeDeletedTab, null);`

`myTabSet.selectTab(0);`

`myTabSet.updateTab(0, myCanvas);`

With the Chrome developer tools I can see that all my widgets are in the page but they're lost somewhere outside the panels. I cannot see how I can link them back to the tabset canvas...

Comment: As the other poster mentioned, this works, so the problem is most likely some *other* code you haven't posted.  Make sure you are calling draw() not RootPanel.add(), and you may be causing core GWT to become involved unnecessarily.  Also, don't call selectTab() before the second call to updateTab() (but this is just a performance tweak, not a fix).

Comment: OK thanks Bill, I'll dig into it and let you know my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've made some test and got the same as you but had some success with the following code:
   1°) in the Javadoc I found:

```
***public void setPane(Canvas pane)
Specifies the pane associated with this tab. You can change the pane associated with a given tab after the TabSet has been created by calling TabSet.updateTab(int, com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Canvas)***
```

I tried without setting to null the pane of tab1 , it didn't work.
I think it could be arranged in better way but anyway the point is to use the `updatePad`method

public static void testTabDelete(){
        final Canvas theCanvas = new Canvas();
        final TabSet theTabs = new TabSet();
        theTabs.setWidth("80%");
        theTabs.setHeight("80%");
        final Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab1");
        final Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab2");
        final Tab tab3 = new Tab("Tab3");
        IButton btn1 = new IButton("Btn1");
        btn1.setLeft(10);
        btn1.setTop(100);
        btn1.setWidth(80);
        theCanvas.addChild(btn1);

```
      IButton btn2 = new IButton("Delete");
      btn2.setLeft(100);
      btn2.setTop(100);
      btn2.setWidth(80);
      btn2.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickEvent event) {

            theTabs.updateTab(0, null);
            theTabs.updateTab(1, theCanvas);                
            theTabs.selectTab(tab2);                
            theTabs.removeTab(tab1);                
        }
    });
      theCanvas.addChild(btn2);     

    theTabs.addTab(tab1);
    theTabs.addTab(tab2);
    theTabs.addTab(tab3);
    tab1.setPane(theCanvas);

    RootPanel.get("container").add(theTabs);        

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but now I get an error message saying that _A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list_.
With the Chrome developer tools I can see that all my widgets are in the page, but they're lost somewhere outside the main panel. It definitely seems that the canvas is not attached to the tabset...

Comment: Which widget are you speaking about can you detail

Comment: I have a complex architecture of vertical and horizontal panels containing buttons, listgrids, labels and images. Plus I have a HTML div that contains a JS chart. I tried all combinations of "updatetab" to unbind the canvas from the tab to be removed and bind it to another tab, but the pane keeps becoming empty when I call "removetab".

Comment: As you mentionned Chrome Dev Tool, I guess you are using Chrome. Did you try under Firefox (Some development are buggy in dev mode under Chrome ....) other point is : could you play with hide and show in place of deleting...